# spring cache key generator why not use spel key？

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cache

keyGenerator not work on spel key,may I custom keyGenerator for all key contains `@Cacheable(key="#spelKey")`

I found code: org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport

```
    protected Object generateKey(Object result) {
        if (StringUtils.hasText(this.metadata.operation.getKey())) {
            EvaluationContext evaluationContext = this.createEvaluationContext(result);
            return CacheAspectSupport.this.evaluator.key(this.metadata.operation.getKey(), this.methodCacheKey, evaluationContext);
        } else {
            return this.metadata.keyGenerator.generate(this.target, this.metadata.method, this.args);
        }
    }
```

change code like：

```
    protected Object generateKey(Object result) {
        if (StringUtils.hasText(this.metadata.operation.getKey())) {
            EvaluationContext evaluationContext = createEvaluationContext(result);
            return this.metadata.keyGenerator.generate(this.target, this.metadata.method, evaluator.key(this.metadata.operation.getKey(), this.methodCacheKey, evaluationContext));
        }
        return this.metadata.keyGenerator.generate(this.target, this.metadata.method, this.args);
    }
```

Comment: I don't understand what the essence of your question is, but there is some documentation how to specify keys with various granularity. https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/cache.html#cache-annotations-cacheable-key

Comment: @JensSchauder yes，but I want write target and method into key，like key=[target,method,params].tojson(), now custom key generator not use of @cacheable(key=#spel)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you're trying to do with `#spelKey` but it's fairly documented. If you want to do something complex, I'd implement a `KeyGenerator` instead, see [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/cache.html#cache-annotations-cacheable-key)

Comment: if use like `@Cacheable(key="#spelKey")`, it can not use KeyGenerater, please see method `generateKey(Object result)`  in
 `org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport`